# Как убрать стандартную подсветку input поля?

Tags: html, css

Как можно убрать стандартную подсветку и выделение `<input>` полей?
Не могу понять, почему поля в разных браузерах иногда выделяются жёлтым (не границы, а само поле, в которое вводится текст), а иногда нет.
Как от этого можно избавиться?

Answer (score 4):

Это функции браузера. Потому и подсветка в разных браузерах разная.

Избавляться от этого (ИМХО) смысла не имеет, потому что пользователь браузера уже привык к подсветке и обращать на нее особого внимания не будет - привык уже к ней...
Но если все-таки надо, то можно настроить в CSS варианты псевдо класса `:focus`.

Например так:

```
input:focus,
select:focus,
textarea:focus,
button:focus {
    background-color: transparent;
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. Это просто просьба заказчика